# Using sleep and usleep interchangeably by creating a class that decides which one to use

Tags: c++, function, class, header, sleep

How would I implement sleep and usleep in a header file. This is what I've tried so far and it isn't working. I am not quite proficient in c++ yet. I know that it is possible to do something similar in HTML by commenting out and each browser uses the code specific to it.

This is the sample I'm practicing with:

**help.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "pause.h"

using namespace std;


int main() {

pause p;    

cout << "Hello";

p.pause(5000)

cout << " World";

}
```

Someone in another thread suggested using #ifdef #else #endif to get it to work between windows and linux/unix

**pause.h**

```
#ifdef _WIN32
    #include <windows.h>


class pause
{
    public:
        void pause(unsigned milliseconds)
        {
            Sleep(milliseconds);
        }
};

#else
        #include <unistd.h>

class pause
{
    public:
        void pause(unsigned milliseconds)
        {
            usleep(milliseconds * 1000); // takes microseconds
        }
};

#endif
```

Somehow though, I must have written the class incorrectly because running my .cpp file it is not recognizing the class or object I tried creating.

**Error**

```
Running /home/ubuntu/workspace/help.cpp
In file included from /home/ubuntu/workspace/help.cpp:2:0:
/home/ubuntu/workspace/pause.h:20:41: error: return type specification for constructor invalid
         void pause(unsigned milliseconds)
                                         ^
/home/ubuntu/workspace/help.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
/home/ubuntu/workspace/help.cpp:9:7: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘p’
 pause p;    
       ^
/home/ubuntu/workspace/help.cpp:13:1: error: ‘p’ was not declared in this scope
 p.pause(5000)
 ^
/home/ubuntu/workspace/help.cpp:15:1: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘cout’
 cout << " World";
 ^


Process exited with code: 1
```

Comment: Omit the `void` return type in the constructor definitions.

Comment: Re: "How would I implement sleep and usleep in a header file" -- you don't **implement** them; they've already been implemented, and you need to **call** them or **use** them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have a member function as the same name as the class. `pause` is the class name, so compiler treats your `pause` function (`pause::pause`) as a constructor.

You can rename the class to say `Pause` and then `p.pause` will call `Pause::pause` function which is valid.

Comment: Why not just pausing by calling the constructor?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize I had done that. I thought maybe I had the structure messed up. I had not been sure if I should make it all one class or one for if and one for else. It seems the latter runs, but now Hello waits for World before it prints.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ If it isn't one thing it's another. I guess that's programming....

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I am not near a Windows computer now, but it seems you have misunderstand some class notation. 
Why had you implemented a constructor `pause::pause` with argument, but call none? And why did you call a member function `pause::pause` that's not there, not to mention it is the same name with `class pause`? you have confused them.

Let me simplify the situation to illustrate this and let you see. 
If you want to print number, set a class `PrintNumber`, by

test.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "print-num.h"

int main(void)
{
   PrintNumber pr;
   pr.printMe(5000);
}
```

print-num.h:

```
#ifndef _PRINTNUM_
#define _PRINTNUM_

#include <iostream>

class PrintNumber
{
public:
   explicit PrintNumber(){};
   ~PrintNumber(){};

   void printMe(unsigned num) { std::cout << num << "\n"; }
};

#endif
```

This will go.

Replace my printing number with you `Sleep()` and try again? 
You may name the class `Pause` with constructor `Pause::Pause(void)`, and a member function `Pause::sleepNow(unsigned)`, or alike.